# SQL Server Collation for Greek, chinese, japanese

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, collections

I've got this multilanguage website that supports greek, chinese and japanese. When I insert values into the database I get question marks all over. My columns are in ntext and my current collation (SQL Server 2008 R2) is Latin1_General_CI_AI_KS.

I did a minor test and switched to Greek collation and inserted some values in greek with no problem. But my site supports multiple languages so I can't explicitly set greek as collation.

What am i missing?

Comment: Use UTF-8. None of the ISO-8859 encodings can support Greek, Chinese, and Japanese.

Comment: Can you show the code where you insert values into the database? If it's with TSQL then you [must use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191313(v=sql.105).aspx) an N prefix: `INSERT ... VALUES (N'ελληνική')`. If you're using an application, then you should be using a parameter with the correct data type. And `ntext` is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx), you should use `nvarchar(max)` instead.

Answer (score -1):

I solven the issue by using a N prefix.